# Приложение не отвечает

Tags: python, discord.py, asyncio, discord-api, disnake

Данный кусок кода успешно выполняется, НО в самом дискорде пишет сообщение о том что Приложение не отвечает.
В самой консоли ошибок не сообщается. По разному искал решение так и не смог добиться ответа. Причем так происходит со всеми слеш-командами.

````
@bot.slash_command(name='broadcast', description='Делает рассылку в зависимости от типа сообщения'
                                                 '.Все доступные типы:str, reboot')
async def streamm(inter: disnake.ApplicationCommandInteraction, types: str, text: str):
    asyncio.sleep(5)
    if inter.author.id == TARGET_USER_ID_TWO or inter.author.id == TARGET_USER_ID_ONE:
        if types == 'str':
            channel = bot.get_channel(TARGET_CHANNEL_ID)
            if channel is not None:
                await channel.send(f'@everyone **{inter.author}** начал стрим!\n {text}')
            else:
                print('Вы не стример, увы и ах.')
        elif types == 'reboot':
            channel = bot.get_channel(TARGET_CHANNEL_ID)
            if channel is not None:
                await channel.send(f'@everyone` Внимание на сервере будут наблюдаться технические работы`')
            else:
                print('У вас нету доступа к данной команде.')
        elif types != 'str' or types != 'reboot':
            channel1 = bot.get_user(inter.author.id)
            await channel1.send(
                'Тип команды не *распознан*. Доступно всего два типа:\n **str** - начало стрима,\n'
                ' **reboot** - технические работы на стороне бота.')```


  Картинка ошибки: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KI2A7.png
````

Comment: Дубликат это, на самом деле. Прежде, чем задавать вопрос, убедитесь, что его до этого не задавали на сайте: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1491180/373173

Answer (score 0):

Дискорд в случае слеш-команд ожидает быстро ответа, и `send` тут не подходит.

Ты можешь в самом начале удалить запрос от пользователя, а потом отправить уже сообщение.

Или же использовать `await inter.response.defer()` в самом начале. Таким образом ты говоришь дискорду, что приложение "думает". Ответ пользтвателю придет. Но так как ты определенно не отвечаешь на команду пользователя у тебя приложение будет бесконечно думать и ждать ответа.

Чтобы ответить именно на запрос используй `inter.response.send_message('текст')`
Так как ты в самом начале ставишь `asyncio.sleep` на 5 секунд

Answer (score 0):

Решение проблемы оказалось невероятно простым. Inter(interaction) должен получить ответ по итогу и в начале функции надо добавить `await inter.response.defer()` и в итоге программы `await inter.edit_original_response('sss')`. Таким образом мы даем ответ изменяя изначальную фразу. defer() и используется для быстрого ответа программе, поэтому использовать ее вместе с asyncio.sleep() не выйдет.